# Whats wrong with this array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
public class lab {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        double[][] g = {RandomArray(3)};
        printArray(g);
    }

    private static void printArray(double[][] g) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(g));
    }

    public static double[][] RandomArray(int n) {

        double[] [] RandomArray = new double[n] [n];
        Random randomNumberCreator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                RandomArray[i][j] = randomNumberCreator.nextDouble() * 100;
            }
        }
        return RandomArray;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my RandomArray method, i want it to work for 2-dimensional arrays but i have clearly made a mistake as the line below is receiving an error and I am unsure as to why this is happening. If you could explain to me the error that I have made i would be grateful.

> double[][] g = {RandomArray(3)};

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Anything starts wit good Naming! for the quick reader `RandomArray(3)` creates a new object of the class `RandomArray`, but in your code it is a method that crates the random array. So do yourself a favor start following Java naming conventions. If that method had a proper name the failing line would be `double[][] g = {createRandomArray(3)};` and that shows that you wrap the array created by your method inside another array dimension resulting in a `double[][][]`. So after renaming the method remove the curly braces.

Comment: It tiresome to repeat it but it takes longer to post a question and wait for an answer than do a search.

Comment: Timothy thanks for helping me understand what i did wrong and why it was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the curly brace around the function Call of "RandomArray"

```
  public static void main (String args[]){
        double[][] g = RandomArray(3);
        printArray(g);
    }

    private static void printArray(double[][] g) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(g));
    }

    public static double[][] RandomArray(int n) {

        double[] [] RandomArray = new double[n] [n];
        Random randomNumberCreator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                RandomArray[i][j] = randomNumberCreator.nextDouble() * 100;
            }
        }
        return RandomArray;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, .-. btw is my method correct? the parameters and arguments etc

Comment: yes - seems fine ;) - had a run local and everything worked out.

Comment: @JokesOnyou *"yes - seems fine ;) – takethefake"* it looks like it would work but it is far from "fine"...

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the  array incorrectly....
you dont need the  **{ }** when calling the method **RandomArray**

just doing `double[][] g = RandomArray(3);` will do the job